# How to call a field of child class in the method of parent class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to print the salary of invoked (any of them) child class in the inherited method of `Detail()`. this cannot be done in this scenario. How would I get the salary with all other details of an employee.

Here is the code

```
using System;

class Employee
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string Gender;
    public string City;

    public void Detail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} \nGender: {1} \nCity: {2} \nID: {3}", Name, Gender, City, ID); //I want to get Yearly or Hourly Salary with these all
    }
}

class PermanatEmp : Employee
{
    public float YearlySalary;

}

class TempEmp : Employee
{
    public float HourlySalary;
}



class Class4
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PermanatEmp pe = new PermanatEmp();
        pe.ID = 101;
        pe.Name = "XYZ";
        pe.Gender = "Male";
        pe.City = "London";
        pe.YearlySalary = 20000;
        pe.Detail(); // how to get Salary with these all 


    }

}
```

Comment: you should override the parent class method in your child class. and write child implementation with your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also using the `virtual/override` method modifiers, but without duplicating code in the child classes. Adjust to your needs:

```
class Employee
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string Gender;
    public string City;

    public virtual void Detail() // add virtual keyword here to allow overrides.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} \nGender: {1} \nCity: {2} \nID: {3}", Name, Gender, City, ID); //I want to get Yearly or Hourly Salary with these all
    }
}

class PermanatEmp : Employee
{
    public float YearlySalary;

    public override void Detail()
    {
        base.Detail(); // prints base class fields.
        Console.WriteLine("Yearly Salary: {0}", YearlySalary);
    }
}

class TempEmp : Employee
{
    public float HourlySalary;

    public override void Detail()
    {
        base.Detail(); // prints base class fields.
        Console.WriteLine("Hourly Salary: {0}", HourlySalary);
    }
}
```

Note: I agree with Jon Skeet that you will have a cleaner and more flexible design if you override the `ToString()` method instead.  But the basic idea is similar either way.

Comment: @sstn Thats it. Thankx

Answer (score 1):

You can't and shouldn't - there's no guarantee that an `Employee` will *have* a salary.

Instead, any class which *does* have a salary can override `ToString` to include all the properties it wants to. I'd suggest overriding `ToString` instead of having a `Detail` method that just prints the information out, by the way.

(As a side note, I would *strongly* advise you not to use public writable fields. [Use properties instead](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx).)

Comment: Thankx ... I am beginner of C# would you please tell me how to override here in this case as this employee have salary, and I want to display his salary as well.

Comment: @QadeerMangrio: Well did you do any research? There are *lots* of tutorials and books explaining how to override methods. I've modified my answer a little - I hadn't spotted that your existing method actually just dumps to the console... it would be better to override ToString in Employee, then override it further in each subclass.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

class Employee
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Gender {get; set;}
   public string City {get; set;}

   public override string ToString() 
   {
    return string.Format("Name: {0} \nGender: {1} \nCity: {2} \nID: {3}", Name, Gender, City, ID);
   }   
}

class PermanatEmp : Employee
{
    public float YearlySalary {get; set;}

        public override string ToString() 
        {
            return base.ToString()+string.Format("\nYearly Salary: {0}"), YearlySalary);
        } 
    }   
}

class TempEmp : Employee
{
     public float HourlySalary {get; set;}
     public override string ToString()  
     {
        return base.ToString()+string.Format("\nHourly Sal:{0}", HourlySalary);
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thankx this helped me alot.

Comment: updated based on sensible suggestion from jon skeet. don't use pub fields and overriding ToString

Answer (score 1):

First of all would be nice to get introduced to virtual and abstract methods:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435(v=vs.71).aspx

In your case you can have a Salary get propery in base class

```
public float Salary { get {return GetSalary();}}
```

where GetSalary is an abstract method of the root object

than you can **override** `protected float GetSalary()` method in each of your child

Answer (score 0):

You should override the Detail method in both PermanatEmp and TempEmp so they each have their own implementation.